# Windows Forms - Repeatedly Running an External Process

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small Windows Forms application that needs to be able to run an external application an unlimited number of times without closing that application after each run.

The external application runs as a single instance and is very resource hungry and slow to load.  The basic workflow is as follows:

1: Wait for a trigger to load the external app
2: Trigger raised, open the external app with a command line reference
3: Monitor a log file
3: External app processes the command line data and writes to the log file
4: Log file changed, so send next command line to (already open) external app
5: Go to step 3

The problem I have is that I cannot find a way of loading the external application without first closing/killing the process.

```
applicationProcess.StartInfo.FileName = commandLine;
applicationProcess.Start();

// Watch for change in log file and then...
applicationProcess.StartInfo.FileName = commandLine;
applicationProcess.Start();
```

and so on, but if I don't

```
applicationProcess.Kill();
```

before I re-issue the applicationProcess.Start() method I get a thread exception.

I think what I need to do is to disconnect from the applicationProcess once it has started, but cannot find any mechanism to do this.

Any advice/direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem by creating a batch file launches the application.  The workflow is as follows:

1: My application launches the batch file with a command-line argument

2: The batch file runs-re-runs the main application

3: My application kills and disposes of the process.

Step 3 simply closes the process that is running the batch file, not the main application process - which I need to stay open.

The batch file couldn't be simpler:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe" %1
```

I have run this on a loop for over one hour and have found no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to launch a new instance of your external application, then just allocate a new Process() object.  Create one Process() object each time you launch your external application, rather than trying to re-use the original one.

If you intend to manipulate an existing instance of your external application, one that you already launched, then you don't need to call Start() again, just continue using applicationProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you create a new `applicationProcess` and keep the old ones in a List or something simmilar?

Comment: Yes, if I create a new ProcessObject for each call it does seem to work, howver I was concerned about adding an unlimited number of process object to the running application as I assume these will consume memory/resources, even if the target application remains as a single instance.

Comment: Yes, but isn't a problem inherent for this kind of design where you run a heavy app repeatedly? Maybe you should think that whole concept over.

Comment: @Neilski, you could always go through the list from time to time and Dispose() any process objects you are not going to use again.